# Create Bitmap from drawable

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, android-bitmap

I would like to add an image (Bitmap) over another one. For that I am only using Bitmaps (fot the image I draw in and the image I add), but the Bitmap I am using is actually a resource in my drawable resource. So Is there a way to create a `Bitmap` that contains my drawable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `decodeResource()` of `BitmapFactory` to convert drawable resource into `Bitmap` as follows...

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), 
    R.drawable.icon_name);
```